# Mimicking Extension Methods in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, extension-methods

Here's an interesting challenge. I was reading through this old issue in TypeScript github to [support Extension Methods](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9) with a usage similar to C#. There are two main approaches proposed, one is to add syntactic sugar to extend object prototype that is often frowned upon, and the other one is to rewrite calls sites (see cons and pros [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9#issuecomment-52329918)).

I was thinking maybe we can do it another way, to mimic extension methods that also works in JavaScript.

Let's say we have the following function:

```js
function includesAnyOf<T>(array: T[], ...searchElements: T[]) {
  return searchElements.some(_ => array.includes(_));
}

// example:
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = 3;
includesAnyOf(a, b); // true

// as extension method it would look like:
// a.includesAnyOf(b);
```

Now I want to implement function `ext` so that I can do:

```
ext(a).includesAnyOf(b)
```

```
ext(a)(_ => _.includesAnyOf(b));
```

preserving all the typings of the parameters. I wonder if that is possible at all, but I started with this and don't know how to finish it!

```js
function ext(obj: any) {
  return {
    includesAnyOf: (...args: any[]) => includesAnyOf(...???)
  };
}
```

I think it's an interesting challenge, how do you think this can be implemented, and how to generalize it, or can you think of a better way?

Comment: You might be interested in the pipeline operator https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator - it's still very early stage though.

Comment: Wow, that's powerful! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I'm not sure why you want `ext(a)` to be a function instead of an extended object.  That is, why do you want to do `ext(a)(x => x.includesAnyOf(1))` instead of just `(ext(a)).includesAnyOf(1)`?

Comment: BTW I think a confounding issue here is that you want higher order types than TS comfortably can deal with, even with [recent improvements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).  If `includesAnyOf` were specifically only dealing with the concrete type `number[]`, you could probably get good strong typing with a generic extender function.  But since you presumably want it to support `T[]` for generic `T`, this is higher order, and you're likely to see `unknown[]` or other prematurely-resolved generics in there.

Comment: @jcalz to answer your first question, I was probably overthinking it! I'm basically looking for the closest path to `a.includesAnyOf(b)` syntax without extending object prototype or cloning the array. So if we can do `ext(a).includesAnyOf(b)` that's even better.

Answer (score 2):

```
function ext<T, E>(obj: T, extension: E) {
   return (receiver: (extended: T & E) => any) => {
      receiver(new Proxy(obj, {
        get(target, prop, receiver) {
          if(prop in extension)
             return extension[prop];
          return Reflect.get(...arguments);
        },
        // TODO has, set, etc. according to needs
      } as T & E));
   };
}

ext(a, { includesAnyOf })(a => {
 a.includesAnyOf("stuff");
});
```

Mission accomplished.

```js
function ext(obj, extension) {
       return (receiver) => {
          receiver(new Proxy(obj, {
            get(target, prop, receiver) {
              if(prop in extension)
                 return extension[prop];
              return Reflect.get(...arguments);
            },
            // TODO has, set, etc. according to needs
          }));
       };
    }
    
    
function includesAnyOf(...searchElements) {
  return searchElements.some(_ => this.includes(_));
}
    
const a = [1, 2, 3];

ext(a, { includesAnyOf })(a => {
  console.log(a.includesAnyOf("stuff"));
});
```

> can you think of a better way?

I honestly don't see any benefit over a regular function. In C# & others it is useful as you can easily find these extensions using autocomplete. No matter how you do that in TS, it won't serve that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for taking the challenge! My goal is to have a more readable code, but only if it doesn't break strong typing and auto-complete.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be working. For `a.includesAnyOf("2")` it returns `false`.

Comment: @orad strings arent numbers

Comment: Thats strongly typed and you get autocompletion on the inner `a`, but you have to type `ext(a, { ...methods })(a => ...)` to get the extensions, and IMO thats just not useful

Comment: You're right, my mistake, but it doesn't compile for me I could only run it in the browser. Yes, the syntax is still verbose and I agree it's not that useful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to do this is to use [lodash.partial](https://lodash.com/docs/#partial) to do the [currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

```js
function includesAnyOf<T>(array: T[], ...searchElements: T[]) {
  return searchElements.some(_ => array.includes(_));
}

import { partial } from 'lodash';

const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = 3;
const ext = (o) => {
  return {
    includesAnyOf: partial(includesAnyOf, o)
  };
};

console.log(
  ext(a).includesAnyOf(b) // true
);
```